# Need help finishing a rig for a 3d scanned Character

Tags: modeling, texturing, rigging, edit-mode, rigify

[image]im un sure how to connect a rig that was already provided to me from the app that helped with the 3d scan and the face rig that is from blender so that i can generate the whole rig as one

Comment: If you want to join several armature, select them and Ctrl J

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)